# Email isn't sent to Hotmail

Tags: rules, webforms, mimemail

I have a webform which sends two emails upon submission:

- To the administrators of the site via webform emails
- To the client who submitted an email via rules using 'send html email'

Everything is working great except when the client's email is hotmail. Hotmail is not receiving the html email. However, if I change the action in rules to 'send mail' it works. Which means that hotmail is not accepting HTML emails.

In the mail system configuration I have the following:

- Site wide default class: MimeMailSystem__SmtpMailSystem
- Mime mail module class: MimeMailSystem__SmtpMailSystem

I don't know what else to look for. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Check your junkmail. Also check if you've created any email filters in your Hotmail.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying, I always check my junk, and it's not there even.

Comment: What's the response of hotmails smtp Server? Can you check that?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, where can I check that?